# I am not able to create the graph for y=sin(x)

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
enter code here
import numpy as np  
import math  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt  
a=np.linspace(3,6,10)  
plt.plot(a,math.sin(a))  
plt.show()
```

**The output says ****TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**

Comment: `math.sin` maps a number to a number. `a` is not a number.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`np.sin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html) or `np.vectorize(math.sin)`.

---

```
import numpy as np  
import math  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt  
a = np.linspace(3,6,10)  
plt.plot(a, np.sin(a))  
plt.show()
```

---

Note that `np.sin`, like `math.sin`, takes *radians* rather than *degrees*, so you may want to adjust your array (`a`) accordingly, or use `np.rad2deg` because at the moment the result is:

[image: plt1]

Whereas if you were to pass in floats between `0` and `2 * math.pi`, you would get a nice sine wave:

[image: plt2]